# Print for Longest common subsequence

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

longestCommonSubsequence is returning the length of LCS.
The code works fine.
But I am trying to print the value of Subsequence .For below example it should print
"acef" .But my code is printing only "ae".
How to fix it?

Here is the complete code
https://pastebin.com/Sq4QMtxF

```
//Code to print the LCS
        int x = a.length();
        int y = b.length();

        String s = "";

        while (x > 0 && y > 0) {
            if (a.charAt(x - 1) == b.charAt(y - 1)) {
                s = a.charAt(x - 1) + s;
                x--;
                y--;
            } else {
                if (memo[x - 1][y] > memo[x][y - 1])
                    x--;
                else
                    y--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if (memo[x - 1][y] > memo[x][y - 1])` be `if (memo[x - 2][y - 1] > memo[x - 1][y - 2])`? The former causes an out of bounds exception, anyways.

Comment: its isnt working.i get out of bounds with ur code.Can you explain how to  print the subsequences value

Comment: I mean, your approach seems fine. The algorithm looks right. I haven't looked close enough to find the error, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to get LCS uses a top down approach and your memo is built from 0,0 and so your answer is at `memo[0][0]`.

In order to get the LCS string from memo you need to traverse from top to bottom. Also use `StringBuilder` instead of adding it to a String ( it will create a new object every time you add to a String ). With that the change will be:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (x < a.length() && y < b.length()) {
    if (a.charAt(x) == b.charAt(y)) {
        sb.append(a.charAt(x));
        x++;
        y++;
    } else {
        if (memo[x + 1][y] > memo[x][y + 1])
            x++;
        else
            y++;
    } 
            
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: thanks it works.canyou point out how can we trace back the solution of DP problems.I am able to solve DPbut not able to recover solution.Eg.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72879470/rod-cutting-problem-print-the-rods-prices

Comment: Use the memo table and see for yourself by writing on paper which path gives the optimum result, then you will know. Usually its the same logic you employ in building the memo.